# Why are the apk sizes identical using conditional compile

Tags: java, android, compilation

I am using conditional compile in Java using the newest Android Studio with newest gradle.

So I did a little test using a

```
    static final boolean compileThisCode = false;
    if (compileThisCode) {
       callALargeClass();
    }
```

and created the apk as well with

```
   static final boolean compileThisCode = true;
```

I would have expected the apks to be of significantly different sizes since the `callALargeClass` is a really large class

But the apks with `compileThisCode = true` and `compileThisCode = false` have the same size

could anyone please help me to understand why that is if Java is doing conditional compile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This influence your runtime memory consumption.
Apk size depends on your libraries and resources (res folder). Even "hello world" in a project with multiple big 3d party libraries you can hit [65k limit](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#about).

You can exclude some unused dependences by [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) config.

Comment: thanks - I understand that - but if it does not compile 50% of my code then I do not understand why the apk has the same size still

Comment: It still holds references to all your functions/classes in the project. You can even hit the problem [65k limit](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Comment: great ... so this is conditional compilation :-)